# ngAnimate unit test not adding class

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm new to unit testing as well as the ng-animate module. I made a simple directive to test out ng-animate.

```
 .directive('slideShow', function ($animate, $compile) {
    return {
      template: '<div class="slide-show-container"></div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var newElement = $compile('<div class="slide-show-slide"></div>')(scope);

        element.bind('mouseenter',function() {
          element.append(newElement);
          $animate.addClass(newElement, 'slide-enter');
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave',function() {
          $animate.removeClass(newElement, 'slide-enter');
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Then I made the following unit test to confirm that the .slide-enter class was being added.

```
  it('should add slide-enter class', function () {
    element.triggerHandler( "mouseenter" );
    expect(element.children().hasClass("slide-enter")).toEqual(true)
  });
```

The directive correctly added the class when I moused over it in a manual test. However the unit test failed and showed that the slide-enter class wasn't being added.

Finally I figured out the only way I could fix it was wrapping the unit test in a $timeout:

```
  it('should add slide-enter class', inject(function ($timeout) {
    element.triggerHandler( "mouseenter" );
    $timeout(function() {
      expect(element.children().hasClass("slide-enter")).toEqual(true);
    });
    $timeout.flush();
  }));
```

Can anyone help me understand why this $timeout is required for the test to work? Is there another way to get this unit test to work that I'm messing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE** I am using angular-animate 1.2.0-rc.2 and have documented my findings with this version.  The need for the `$timeout.flush()` call seems to be fixed when looking at the 1.2.0-rc.3 code but I have not tested it yet. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ngAnimate/animate.js

---

I had the same problem with one of my tests. I was able to get my test to work by just calling `$timeout.flush()` after I had called the code that was supposed to trigger the adding of the class and before I called the `expect`.  Your test should work if you rewrite it like:

```
it('should add slide-enter class', inject(function ($timeout) {
  element.triggerHandler( "mouseenter" );
  $timeout.flush();  
  expect(element.children().hasClass("slide-enter")).toEqual(true);
}));
```

I had to dig into the ngAnimate code to figure it out and this is what I found.

If you take a look at the `angular-animate.js` file at the `addClass` function.  You will see the following:

```
addClass : function(element, className, done) {
  performAnimation('addClass', className, element, null, null, function() {
    $delegate.addClass(element, className, done);
  });
}
```

The closure that is the last parameter to `performAnimation` is what will finally add the class.

In `performAnimation`, that last parameter is named 'onComplete`. There is a section of code that deals with calling this closure when animations should be skipped:

```
//skip the animation if animations are disabled, a parent is already being animated
//or the element is not currently attached to the document body.
if ((parent.inheritedData(NG_ANIMATE_STATE) || disabledAnimation).running) {
  //avoid calling done() since there is no need to remove any
  //data or className values since this happens earlier than that
  //and also use a timeout so that it won't be asynchronous
  $timeout(onComplete || noop, 0, false);
  return;
}
```

And there is the call to `$timeout` that is causing the problem.  When running this code in an angular test, the call to `$timeout` simply queues up the closure.  The test code then has to call `$timeout.flush()` in order to get that function to run.

Comment: Nice detective work! That explains everything. Glad to see that it  seems to be fixed it in the new version.